# Add styles to matched items in for loop angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I've a list of array items `['Mark', 'John']`.

I want to find `Mark` in the `items` array and highlight it with some colors.

I wanted to add `highlighted` class to the matched `li` tag

How can i do it angular 2? Please help

```js
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  public items = ['Mark', 'John'];
  show: boolean;
  onSubmit(text: string) {
    if (this.items.includes(text)) {
      this.show = true;
    } else {
      this.items.push(text);
      this.show = false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" #text/>
  <button (click)="onSubmit(text.value)">Add</button>

  <div *ngIf="show">
    Item Already Exits
  </div>

  <div>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of items">
        {{item}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can conditionally set a class in angular that checks for a property.

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items" [class.highlighted]="item==='Mark'">{{item}}</li>
```

The *item* from the *ngFor is already accessible in the tag you are using it on. The [class.highlighted] is followed by the condition, in this case by simply checking if the current item equals Mark. So highlighted is only applied as a class if the condition is true.

Hope this helps.

Comment: is it possible to do it with inline-styles without class ?

Comment: I think you can also set specific inline attributes (for example the color) like this: `<li [style.color]="item==='Mark'? 'red' : 'green'">`, but I'm note sure if there is a way to do multiple styles in one html attribute. Check this one out: [https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#style-binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#style-binding)